System does not awake when touch screen is pressed
I use an HP Engage One Pro All in One system with Ubuntu 24.04 LTS installed.
I experience the following behavior:  When the system goes into screen saver mode, or power save mode, it will not respond when I press the touchscreen.  When I press a key on the keyboard, or do a mouse click, the system wakes-up and shows desktop.
Does anyone has an idea how to achieve this function? I have search the internet for clues, but couldn't find anything about this topic.

Do you have screensaver in your settings and can you disable it?

Hi, no, there is no screensaver installed, or active, only powersave; blank, turn the screen off after a period of inactivity (5min).

The only thing I found that may solve your problem is running xorg and installing xscreensaver.

Hi Amar,  I have disabled Powersave options and installed xscreensaver, set xscreensaver to show "blanc screen only" and time to 30 minutes, this works!

If I set it as answer can you accept it?

thank you to think along.

yes, that's ok for me

Unfortunately nothing is available in Wayland for now
Howerver there is a possibility: xorg.
Change to xorg by:

Restart computer.
Select the small cog on the bottom right corner at the login screen.
Choose 'Ubuntu on Xorg' and login.
Disable Powersave.
Install xscreensaver sudo apt install xscreensaver and configure it as you see fit.

